# MFC with wglew for OpenGL 3.X context

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, mfc

I have a MFC application which supports only OpenGL 1.1.0 version. I want to change the OpenGL context from 1.1 to 3.3 or latest version. I tried a lot of ways from the website to make changes. But it is not working properly. Although I created another mfc application with 4.4.0 version of OpenGL.

Actually none of the option of "gl/wglew.h" file is working. glewInit() gives no error.

> wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context")

always gives zero always. What's the way to on the wglew option and make a 4.4.0 version of OpenGL?

Comment: How is this related to MFC?

Comment: I am creating an MFC application. And I need to create an OpenGL context in that.

Comment: GLEW does not know or care about MFC. Whether you use MFC to create windows the easy (or rather the hard way) is of no relevance to this question.

Comment: This is related to MFC, though only indirectly. Whatever code you are using to setup your MFC control appears to be selecting a hardware incompatible (GDI-only) pixel format. You should include the relevant calls to `ChoosePixelFormat (...)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I read about a bit of choosePixelFormat and found the problem..

Comment: [`ChoosePixelFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318284.aspx) is a Windows API call, that takes a `HDC` argument. MFC is not even remotely related.

Comment: @Iinspectable: It most certainly is. MFC wraps window creation, which is where `HDC` comes from (it usually refers to the client rectangle of an `HWND`). You do not pull a window out of thin air, the call to `ChoosePixelFormat` is going to occur in an MFC event handler for window creation.

Comment: @Iinspectable: Sorry, replace `HDC` with `HRC` in that last comment. The fact of the matter is that `ChoosePixelFormat (...)` is only the first step in a series of Win32 and WGL API calls that can only take place once a window is created, which MFC wraps.

Comment: @Andon Whether you call `CreateWindow` or `CWnd::Create` makes no difference. Whether you call `ChoosePixelFormat` in your `WM_CREATE`-handler or your `OnCreate`-method makes no difference. MFC doesn't do anything magically different, or demand a radically different approach. It's just there, to make the OP's life harder. Other than that, it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @IInspectable: By that logic, the language a program is written in is completely irrelevant because it runs the same API and we should eliminate language tags from all OpenGL questions on Stack Overflow. I am not saying that MFC is a huge part of this question, but it certainly is relevant. Had that detail been left out, I would not have known that he was handling context creation without a separate library such as GLUT, GLFW, SDL, etc. Language bindings and window API are important in answering OpenGL questions.